# Tilde (~) sign not working as expected

Tags: html, asp.net, tilde

I'm getting very inconsistent result with the tilde - now that my site is using a shared plan. I have a domain (www.domain.com, for example) that is pointing to a folder /sites/domain.com, where all my files are hosted. The host company redirects calls to my domain name, to that folder.

I have this in my page:

```
<a runat="server" href="~/default.aspx">
                                <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/main_icon.png" BorderStyle="None"/></a>
```

However, the image isn't resolving.

When I upload, and view source, I get this:

```
<a href="sites/mydomain/default.aspx">
                                <img src="sites/mydomain/Images/main_icon.png" style="border-style:None;" /></a>
```

And this isn't resolving, because I'd expect it to be:
 /default.aspx

and

/Images/main_icon.png

How should I be doing this?

Removing the tilde works (this is a master page), but when I navigate to a page in a sub folder, it fails.

Comment: Is you site configured as an application? Also, what happens if you remove the ~ but leave the /, e.g. "/Images/main_icon.png" ?

Comment: Yuriy - I'm not 100% sure about the application part. How do I check? I think it is. As far the /, it seems to work sometimes, until I navigate to something like /users/edituser.aspx ...

Comment: You can check in properties of virtual directory if you have access to IIS otherwise it should be available in control panel of  your host (ask host if unsure). ~ resolved to application root and it looks like it point to the top level applications.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be something based on the folder structure of Windows vs. Unix? Did you build your site in Unix and it's deployed through your domain with a Windows server?

Windows and Unix use different identifiers for their home folders. Windows just uses a %userprofile% and Unix uses ~, or $HOME(cd $HOME or cd ~).

I'd comment on your question, but I don't quite have enough reputation to do that.